SwiftUI iOS 16+ apps check if the top view is A NavigationStack or a Modal. and push or present a view from a deep link
In SwiftUI iOS 16+ app I have a deep link logic in the SceneDelegate.
According to the URL I can switch on it and navigate or present the ViewController that I want to show either inserting it to a NavigationController or presenting a Modal by finding the top ViewController with this logic :
extension UIApplication {
    class func getTopViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)

        } else if let tab = base as? UITabBarController, let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: selected)

        } else if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}

In a SwiftUI app where I don't have a top ViewController how do I decide if to append the current view from the deep link logic to a NavigationStack path or to present it Modally?
Thanks for the help.
